# php excel Number Validation

Tags: php

I am using php PEAR package to generate MS excel file to allow users supply data offline before uploading.

I need to carry out some numeric validation on specific cells. I want something like this:

```
cell 1: value<=5 (max=5)
cell 2: value<=10 (max=10)
cell 3: value<=15 (max=15)
```

My code:

```
require_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php';
$workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
$filename = "Validate.xls"; 
$workbook->send($filename);
$worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet('Number validation');
 

$worksheet->write(0, 0, 'S/N');
$worksheet->write(0, 1, 'VALUE 2');
$worksheet->write(0, 2, 'VALUE 3');
$worksheet->write(0, 3, 'VALUE 4');


$worksheet->write(1, 0, '1');
$worksheet->write(1, 1, '0');
$worksheet->write(1, 2, '0');
$worksheet->write(1, 3, '0');


$workbook->close();
```

In my search I came across https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.validate.validate.number.php but don't know how to modify the code above with

```
require_once 'Validate.php';

if (Validate::number(8.0004, array('decimal' => '.', 'dec_prec' => 4))) {
    echo 'Valid number';
}
```

to make it validate the user input offline

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Your code isn't actually using any user input (you have things hardcoded atm).  What do you want to happen with an invalid number?

Comment: The user input is not at the code level. The code generates an Ms excel file which the user is to fill. During filling, I intend that there should be an error pop to notify the user if the user attempts to exceed the maximum value in the given cell. Please note that this validation is not done at the code level but at the downloaded Ms excel file. I hope my explanation is clear enough? Thank you for your response.